# Save As Dialog Error with 'HtmlTextArea' object has no attribute 'ExportText'

Tags: .net, ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to create a save as dialog popup. The script prompts for the user to input a file name and file type however I keep getting this error before it stops running:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 21, in AttributeError: 'HtmlTextArea' object has no attribute 'ExportText'

```
import System
from System.IO import FileStream, FileMode
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot
from  Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers

import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import SaveFileDialog

SaveFile = SaveFileDialog()
SaveFile.Filter = "Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"   #file type saving to
SaveFile.ShowDialog()
saveFilename = SaveFile.FileName
print "saveFilename=", saveFilename

from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent,TablePlotColumnSortMode
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Export import DataWriterTypeIdentifiers 
from System.IO import File, StreamWriter

writer = Document.Data.CreateDataWriter(DataWriterTypeIdentifiers.ExcelXlsDataWriter)
stream = StreamWriter(saveFilename)
te = summaryCrossTable.As[VisualContent]()
te.ExportText(stream)                          # the error occurs here
```

Comment: figured it out!